# Какие преимущества парадигмы ООП при создании сайтов?

Tags: php, ооп

Какие преимущества может дать использование парадигмы ООП (классы, объекты, методы, трейты, ...) при создании сайтов?

Comment: Для того же, для чего в любом другом виде программирования. Для структурирования кода, уменьшения локальной сложности и как результат к лучшей управляемости проектом

Comment: Смотря каких сайтов. Для лендинга обычного использовать ООП скорее всего избыточно. А вот проект посложнее легче делать с ООП, чтобы не запутаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ООП нужно чтобы потом сайт (программу) можно было поддерживать, оно в первую очередь помогает отделить мух от котлет и навести порядок в голове и в коде.

Как и везде вы можете либо свалить все в кучу, либо выстроить снежинки (структурированную систему)

На один раз может быть это и избыточно, но через год Вы себе спасибо скажете, что сгруппировали кучу свойств в объекты или инкапсулировали алгоритмы и отделили их от данных.

ООП позволяет использовать один и тот же программный код с разными данными. На основе классов создается множество объектов, у каждого из которых могут быть собственные значения полей. С объектами нет необходимости вводить множество переменных. В этом смысле объекты похожи на структуры данных. Объект можно представить как некую упаковку данных, к которой присоединены инструменты для их обработки – методы.

**Наследование** позволяет не писать новый код, а использовать и настраивать уже существующий за счет добавления и переопределения методов.

**Инкапсуляция** позволяет объединить и защитить данные и код в объект и скрыть реализацию объекта от пользователя. При этом пользователю предоставляется только спецификация (интерфейс) объекта.

Comment: Изучение ООП в дальнейшем пригодится ?(Для Back-end разработчиков)

Comment: @LuricSapi более чем

Comment: Мне как для начинающего Бек-енд программисту посоветуешь учить ООП : постепенно или сразу?

Comment: @LuricSapi зависит от желания, рано быть не может

Comment: Кто-то даже минусанул, то есть я не прав?

Comment: Хз , вполне нормально объяснил вроде

Comment: особо интересно выглядит скрытие реализации в пхп :)

Comment: процедурный код тоже позволяет использовать блоки кода  разными данными, это стало возможным с тех пор как в принципе появились процедуры и функции, и не важно, ООП они или нет.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не забудте про MVC

Comment: @teran, а что по Вашему не так в пхп со скрытием реализации?

Comment: @Jigius да каламбурно просто выглядит "сокрытие реализации объекта от _пользователя_" , когда пользователь видит исходный код :)

Comment: @teran, понял :)